# How to get this layout in a scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview

So i want to have a layout like on the image :
[image: Desired layout]
An image to the left then the title and then below of those the text. 
I can't seem to do it while having a scrollview!

So this is my code while NOT using the scrollview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewH"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewIntroText"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
              android:text="@string/intro" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageViewLOGO"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:src="@drawable/klein" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageViewBlock"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
              android:src="@drawable/block" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewBMWText"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
              android:text="@string/bmwtext" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewBMWTitle"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textViewIntroText"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
              android:text="@string/bmw" />
```

How do i achieve the same results but with a scrollview?

Anyway, thanks for your time! I appreciate every answer/comment!

Comment: It is always a good idea to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This question has a bunch of superfluous code that doesn't even attempt replicate the problem. It's like going to a mechanic with a perfectly good car, showing it to him, and then asking him what's wrong with your broken down car back home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have my AS near to me but you can try with this please:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

//all your xml here

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `RelativeLayout` to `wrap_content`. If the child view is the same size as the `ScrollView`, obviously it will not scroll.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Although i don't want the whole page to be a scrollview this is something that i will definitely use later! Thank you!